# How do I create Map with regions from Scratch

Tags: qgis, choropleth, create

I wish to create [choropleth map](https://datavizcatalogue.com/methods/images/anatomy/choropleth.png) in R (or any other program).

The map I want to use cannot be found, hence I must create one from scratch (will use [photo of map from 1800s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esfF0.jpg)). This involves

1- Drawing boundaries
2. Naming boundaries
3. Giving numerical value to boundaries

So far, I found this (https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/making_a_map.html), but it doesn't answer my question.

What do I google to find this?

Comment: Well, what IS your question? How to create a map? Then have a look at the QGIS documentation/tutorial. How to search for a guide on creating maps? Then google for the QGIS documentation/tutorial.

Comment: If you want your map to be located in the correct latitude-longitude position, the first thing to do is to "georeference" your photo - this matches points on the photo with points on the ground. Find a tutorial for that and come back here with details if you get stuck.